# Why won't Mojang let me login to my account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I tried and tried but it didn't work. I bought minecraft for PC/Mac and did all of that stuff, got it downloaded, entered my account information and BA BAM! This shows up.[image: Minecraft: Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers.]

I changed my password and made sure the servers were connected. I tried EVERYTHING to fix it, so what happened?

Comment: Due to my lack of telepathy and man-machine brain interface, I am unable to query the Minecraft servers for the relevant data for you.

Comment: I'm actually really disappointed at how difficult it was for me to find hardcore pornography newsletters to sign you up for.

Comment: @DeadMG Probably because the won't let you create multiple accounts on the same email.

Comment: Since you've tried *everything*, I'm afraid we can't help.

Comment: Have you got a firewall? Looks to me like Minecraft's servers are blocked on your computer.

Comment: @DeadMG [;)](http://puu.sh/jCeXV/0ebcb237c6.png)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that Windows Firewall is not blocking the internet features for your Minecraft (launcher)

Comment: Gylyan you should go into more detail into how to actually check the WIndows Firewall :).